# Converting Xamarin.iOS code to native?

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin.ios, abstract-class

I want to convert my Xamarin.iOS base classes to native, so that I can also develop native when a project only needs to be done in iOS.

Now I have abstract classes inheriting from `UICollectionViewSource`, and I don't really know how I can put this in Swift, as it is protocol oriented. I could go the "abstract" way and throw `fatalerror`s when a property or method needs to be overridden.

Or I could go the protocol way, and have my `UICollectionViewSource subclass` take a protocol, which leads to nicer code completion and you won't forget to implement anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the closest thing would be with protocol and extensions. This way you can provide a default implementations for the methods that have one.

```
protocol MyCollection : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func foo() -> Double
    func fooAbstract() -> Double
}

// provide default implementations
extension MyCollection {
    func foo() -> Double{
        return Double.infinity;
    }
}

// requires missing methods to be implemented
class  NewCollection : MyCollection {
    ...
}
```

EDIT to answer your question. I am not 100% if this is what you mean but I don't have trouble calling the "virtual" methods from the extension. Here is a sample using something other than UICollection source (too many methods to implement :)).

```
protocol MyTwo{
        func fooA2() -> Bool
}

protocol MyCollection : MyTwo {
    func foo() -> Double
    func fooAbstract() -> Double
}

// provide default implementations
extension MyCollection {
    func foo() -> Double{
        if fooA2() {
            return Double.infinity;

        }

        return 0;
    }
}

class  NewCollection : MyCollection {
    func fooAbstract() -> Double{
        return foo();
    }

    func fooA2() -> Bool {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The extension can't use methods and properties defined in the protocol (so in your example: in `extension MyCollection`, inside the body of `foo()` I can't use `fooAbstract()`). Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Edited the sample. I was able to call methods on both the base protocol and the derived protocol inside the extension.